# How to solve the problem with static compilation of GLFW application in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, static, glfw, glu

This my compilation command for app.

```
# inside file grun.sh
g++ $1  -pthread -static -o  glapp -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lglfw && ./glapp $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 && rm ./glapp
```

While running above command with my application file.

```
$ grun Myapplication.cpp
```

get error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*It runs fine with without `-static` options though, but I want to make my app statically compiled, Please help me how should I do it?*

Comment: What do you mean by statically compiled? Applications always compile to executables. That's it.  Do you want to avoid dependencies on shared objects? Then you need to link against static variants of all the libraries in use.